# How to override a class using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

A jQuery CSS class sets the following:

```
 .newwidget { border: 1px solid #5a9ee9; background: #5a9ee9 url(t6.gif) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; padding:3px 3px 3px 10px; font-size:10px}
```

How can this class be overridden and a new class added so that I can put different styles in it? Maybe I have to remove before classes before adding them. How is this done?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to redefine newwidget so that all elements with that class have a new style? Or are you trying to change the class of an existing element?

Comment: Just so you know, while removing the old class is an option, it is not required. If there are styles in the old one you want to use, just use `addClass()`, which will 'enhance' the element with the styles in the new class. Otherwise, use the solutions given below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the class selector with addClass and removeClass.

```
$('.newwidget').removeClass('newwidget').addClass('newerwidget');
```

Answer (score 17):

I think it's worth noting that you can **remove all** the classes by leaving off the parameter from `removeClass()`:

```
$('.newwidget').removeClass().addClass('newerwidget');
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking to completely replace the existing classes on an element, you can use the .attr() method.

```
$('#elementId').attr('class', 'newClassName');
```

Any classes on elementId will be replaced.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery defines `addClass()` and `removeClass()` for just this purpose:

```
$("#ElementId").removeClass('oldClassName').addClass('newClassName');
```

The two function do the obvious. Chain them like this to change the class all in one action.

If you would like to change all elements from 'oldClass' to 'newClass', you can use a selector like this:

```
$(".oldClassName").removeClass('oldClassName').addClass('newClassName');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can to [remove](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) the old class and [add](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) a new one:

```
$myJQObject.removeClass('newwidget').addClass('newclass');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).removeClass('oldClass').addClass('newClass');
```